# Database design for a chat system

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-design, real-time, bigdata

I know there is a lot of posts out there discussing Db design for a chat system, but they didn't explain anything about the scalability of that design, so here my question.

I want to design a Db of a real-time chat between 2 or more users, let's take 2 users first, here what I came up with.

**Table 1:**

name: *User*

fields: id, name

**Table 2**

name: *Chat Room*

fields: id, user1, user2

**Table 3**:

name: *Message*

fields: Chat_room_id, user_id, message

Now considering Facebook in mind, it has around 2 billion active users per month and let say 1 billion of them indulge in chatting and each user sends 100 messages.

which make 100 Billion entries in table: **Message**, so the question is,

"Will Mysql or Postgres be able to handle this much of entries and show particular chat room messages in real-time ?" if not then what should be the best practice to follow that, I know that it also depends on the server on which RDBMS is installed but still want to know the optimum architecture.

PS: I am using Django as backend and AngularJs for asynchronous behavior

Comment: Seems like poor design. As a rule, any time you have enumerated columns, you can be sure that the design is flawed. This case is certainly not the exception.

Comment: yes, you are right that this is a poor design , thats my question , how a good design should look like in this case ?

Comment: That aside, the scale envisaged is wholly disproportionate. Facebook employs a wide variety of architectures to manage its data set. As and when your rival technology came to surpass Facebook, I'm confident that you'd either be rich enough to pay a professional to look into these issues for you, or too rich to care.

Comment: totally agree with you, i am not competing facebook , i am a student , so i want to know what kind of technologies and tool i should use for this task , lets not assume 100 Billion its too much, but lets take 10 Million

Comment: A normalised design *might* have a table of chatroom_participants with a chatroom column, and a participant column, with a single value entered in each, and a PRIMARY KEY formed on the combination of those two columns.

Comment: A chat room can only ever have 2 participants?  Sounds less like a "chat room" and more like a direct messaging system.  "User" and "Message" seem like the primary entities here.  "Message" would indeed grow very large very quickly.  Sharding that table across multiple servers may be a valid approach to handle scale, at least long enough until the resources available to you from such a popular service open your possibilities a lot more.  ("Scale" is often not something you need right away, and is just as much a business/financial concern as a technical one.)

Comment: MySQL can handle 10 million data points.

Comment: @david a chatroom can have multiple participants. The op was using 2 only as a starting point.

Comment: @Strawberry: Hmm... In that case the intended UX is then going to change the design a bit.  Whether it becomes necessary to record when users were in chatrooms for historical purposes is a significant question for the design.  Maybe an "enter/exit" log table, seems better than horizontally recording users as proposed (and against which you also originally commented).  Since participation in a room changes over time and isn't static at all.  It'll grow too, but not as quickly as the messages table.

Comment: @david yes i am taking 2 users as a starting point , but it can be a group chat as well and in that case number of messages will increase drastically

Comment: Anything seems better than horizontally recording users!

Comment: @Strawberry yes the main problem is the leaf node table i.e **Message**, because we have to filter all messages from them and its size can be huge, i think the point david mentioned that Sharing Message table on multiple server can be a help here

Comment: @Strawberry , i will not be recording users horizontally , i just did that above for the starter point , but in actually there will be seperate table Participants , in which user will be pointed to his chat room

Comment: You're still trying to solve problems that haven't happened yet.

Comment: @Strawberry lol i know it did'nt happened , all i am asking are step wise approaches that will take me to the optimum structure

Comment: The structure evolves with demand. That's my point.

Comment: Do you understand how many servers Facebook, Twitter, Yahoo, Google, etc, _each_ have?  For that matter, how many datacenters each owns?  In this forum we can begin to discuss 1 billion rows.  For 100 billion rows, you need team of dozens or hundreds of experts in various areas.

Comment: Do the math.  How much disk space would 100 billion rows take?  Can you even buy a disk that big.  No.  A SAN?  Maybe.  Now do the math on how long it would take to write 100B rows at, say, 1 per millisecond.  Not a pretty picture.  And we have not yet started talking about MySQL/Postgres/etc.; they can't go faster than disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

100 Billions rows in one table will never work online. Not only all possible partitioning ways are applied to reduce the sizes, but also separation of active/passive data strategies. But nevertheless all the high maters, the answer:

**Postgres is indeed effective working with big data itself.**

and yet:

**Postgres has not effective enough strategy to fight poor design**

Look at your example: table *chat_room* lists two users in separate columns - what for? You have user_id in messages referencing users.id. And you have chat_room.id in it, so you have data which users were in that chat_room. Now if your idea was to pre-aggregate which users participated in chat_room over time or at all, make it one array column, like `(chat_room.id int, users_id bigint[])` or if you want join time and leave time, add corresponding attributes. active/passive data can be implemented using archived chat_rooms in different relation then active ones. Btw aggregation on who participated in that chatroom can be performed on such archiving...

Above is not instructions for action, just expression. There is no best practice for database schema. First make a clear plan what your chat will do, then make db schema, try it, improve, try, improve, try, improve and so on, until everything works. If you have concerns on how it will work with 100 billions of rows - fill it up and check...